# Creating and preparing database postgres "no such file or directory"

Tags: postgresql, postgis

During preparing database according to [How to import OpenStreetMap data into PostgreSQL](http://programmingerrors.blogspot.sk/2013/07/how-to-import-openstreetmap-data-into.html) i always get error message C:/Program: No such file or directory after writing `psql -U postgres -d gis -f PATH_TO_POSTGRES/share/contrib/postgis-1.5/postgis.sql` In my case path looks like : `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\share\contrib\postgis-2.1\postgis.sql`
Thank you for help or advices

Comment: Try quoting you path or prepending a `\\` to the space in your path.

Comment: I have tried add "\" to the space it did not work but quoting my path worked perfectly! Thank you so much ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
psql -U postgres -d gis 
   -f "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\share\contrib\postgis-2.1\postgis.sql"
```

Here Program Files is separated with space so you need to add double quote around the path.